# Possible to use GPT for specific set of documents?

Tags: gpt

I have a 100+ PDF documents regarding a company's policies, procedures and guidelines etc.

Is there an AI tool that was trained in general understanding of language, that I can feed all those PDFs and make my own model where I can ask questions about the company's rules and procedures specifics, find relevant pieces of information and get answers based on the documents provided?

I know I can feed a PDF to an AI and summarize it, but I'm looking for a permanent solution, kind of like a database but where instead of standard search I could have a conversation with AI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fine-tune a model with your own documents: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning

You can also fine tune other models, like if you needed one that ran locally.

Alternatively, you could do it in stages of prompts. Fed the model the documents and have it create a list of tags for topics in each document, then include that in your initial prompt. So when you ask a question the first time, the prompt context includes the generated document tags, and you're actually asking "what documents would be useful to answer this question?", then take that response, get the documents, send another prompt "with these documents, answer this question", then return that answer to the user.